# Illustrated Space Tourist book featuring Behemoth's World

Tags: story-identification

Illustrated book about space tourism.

It was a shortish book, but with large illustrated pages, about a future space cruise through the galaxy visiting a number of outlandish planets.

The one illustration I've been able to find was by Richard Clifton-Dey, called *Behemoth's World*.

[image: Behemoth's World]

Comment: It might help to identify the book if you provide more information such as what language it was in, when you read it, etc.

Comment: ... and I always thought this was only the cover art for Blue Oyster Cult's "Cultosaurus Erectus" album...

Comment: Aha, so [that's where the album cover came from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult%C3%B6saurus_Erectus).

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244217/early-1980s-graphic-novel-about-human-spies-undercover-on-an-intergalactic-cruis (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Comment: Apologies all, I missed this.  I have marked the answer as accepted - thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be [*Tour of the Universe: The Journey of a Lifetime: The Recorded Diaries of Leio Scott and Caroline Luranski*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?514569) by Robert Holdstock and Maloclm Edwards? 143 pages, published in 1980. It's the only book about "cruise" featured in ISFDB, that contains the work you attached to your question.

From a review on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2175291.Tour_of_the_Universe):

> The story of a couple who win a tour across the galaxy, and the complications that pile up on their trip. The story is told through journal entries, painted scenes, and various futuristic documents.

Or from [Google Books](https://books.google.com.tr/books/about/Tour_of_the_Universe.html?id=Ax9JoMxpmm4C&redir_esc=y) summary:

> Two winners of a trip with the first package tour to the Aurora-Magellan Federation spend six months visiting alien planets

Printed version is available in various locations, most notably on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0831787988). Alas, no e-book version exists to my knowledge, but it's possible to use search engines to find the works in that book as they're all listed on the relevant [Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?514569) page.

This is what the cover is supposed to look like:

[image]

And here are some other works from the same book:

[image]

<sub>On the left - *Hall of a Thousand Races* by Les Edwards, appears 2 pages before the image in you question; on the right - *Earthport* by Jim burns, appears on the cover and on page 10.</sub>

Comment: Thank you massively!  I have found and purchased a copy of this on eBay and it's exactly what I was looking for.