# 1970's sci-fi anthology featuring a helmeted woman with a tiny, crustacean-like body on the cover?

Tags: story-identification

**Details**

I remember this one being a paperback sci-fi anthology or magazine in my dad's collection.  I think it may have been a "Best of" annual or otherwise related to a science fiction magazine.

As stated in the title, the cover had a bizarre, somewhat grotesque image on the cover.  The head of a human woman, wearing either a space helmet or perhaps an underwater helmet.  I think the metal part was dark brown, and there was a flat glass faceplate in front.  The body attached to the head was tiny, and reminded me vaguely of a prawn, or similar creature.  As best as I can remember, anyway.   It really freaked me out at the time (I was four or five, IIRC). That much I am certain of!

I'm almost positive this one comes from the 1970s.

I know there's not much to go on here, but does this ring any bells with anyone?

Comment: Great to see you on the site, Helbent! I thought you burnt up on re-entry!

Comment: Rumors of my death were greatly exaggerated, mostly by the Spacethings.  Besides, I was dying a lot more frequently under my original handle (redshirt crewmember).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perhaps the 1975 [Ace Books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ace_Books) edition of the anthology [*Best Science Fiction Stories of the Year, Second Annual Collection*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?4191) edited by [Lester del Rey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lester_del_Rey)?

[image]

Comment: _Drops jaw in awe_ - how did you find it?

Comment: *Aieeee*!  All these years later, and that cover STILL freaks me out!  That is the cover I was thinking of, no question.

Comment: @Gallifreyan You're asking me to disclose my methods, but you can't spare an upvote?

Comment: I used a simple *Findum Bookum* spell.

Comment: Was out of votes yesterday evening. Now can you disclose them? :)

Comment: @Gallifreyan The ISFDB is my friend. I did an advanced title search with the settings "Title type is exactly ANTHOLOGY" and "Title year is exactly 197_" and "Title contains best". The database had fewer than 150 anthologies published in the 1970s with "best" in their title. I started clicking through them and looking at the cover pictures, and as luck would have it the winner was in the top couple dozen or so.

Comment: ISFDB is cool. Used it to look up [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/151748/70236) of mine, though it does require some creative search items :)

Comment: @Gallifreyan The original question had both the name of [the artist](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?26442) *and* the title of [the illustration](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1872409)? And it wasn't closed as "general reference"? :-)

Comment: Now that I've answered, it can be closed :)